# Celery: Abort or revoke group in django celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using django celery. I know i can revoke task by using below code

```
app.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

Can i use above code to remove group if the how can i get group id

Comment: You can revoke multiple tasks using a list of task IDs; https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#revoking-multiple-tasks

Comment: but i want to remove group containing all the task at once

Comment: I'm still looking for the solution...